# find an id inside a multiline string

Tags: c#

i need to extract an id from a text i receive programmatically.
the only thing i know is that the id always starts with a capital letter, this letter can only be A, R or V.
the other elements of the id are just numbers and are always 14 (so the id is always 15 characters long)

```
A18080000010866 for example
```

the text I receive instead can contain any character and is often on several lines, but I'm sure it contains only one id.

how do i do this kind of research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regular expressions, such as:

```
var r = new Regex(@"[ARV]\d{14}"); //it means "A, R or V followed by digits 14 of"
var id = r.Match(input).ToString();
```

Also look at `r.Matches()` in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-5.0) if your input will have multiple IDs.

Here is [an example of using r.Match()](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w1a5IK)

You'll need to `using System.Text.RegularExpressions` to access the Regex class